# Download File - Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-storage, file-transfer

I am trying to download a copy of my mysql history to keep on my local drive as a safeguard.

[image: The console window with visible cog in corner]
Once selected, a dropdown menu appears
[image: console window with dropdown menu]
And I am prompted to enter the file path for the download
[image]

But after all the variations I can think of, I keep receiving the following error message:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Download File` means that you are downloading a file from the VM to your local computer. Therefore the expected path is a file on the VM.

If instead your want to `upload` c:\test.txt to your VM, select `Upload File`. Then enter `c:\test.txt`. The file will be uploaded to your home directory on the VM.